# Why do I have a 3 wire/double pole breaker for kitchen receptacle?

Tags: electrical, gfci, circuit-breaker

I am switching my kitchen receptacle to a GFI; it has 3 wires.  I'm pretty sure I have to break the bar between the two hot screws, thus making the top and bottom on a separate circuit.  What is the reason for this way of wiring? The outlet is not feeding anything else, it's on its own circuit with a double pole 15amp breaker. Seems a little useless to me. The house was built in 1978.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a multi wire branch circuit. You cannot connect a normal GFCI receptacle as you're describing because you'll effectively have a shared neutral with one of the hots on the gfci. See [How do I install a GFCI receptacle with two hot wires and common neutral?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9293/how-do-i-install-a-gfci-receptacle-with-two-hot-wires-and-common-neutral) and [Is this a “shared neutral” situation?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/16693/2196)

Comment: What are the colors of the three wires? Do you know if the same circuit breaker currently controls both the upper and lower outlets?

Comment: This almost sounds like the outlet under a kitchen sink, where there is a single duplex receptacle with one circuit for a dishwasher and a second circuit for a garbage disposal.